# Slick way to count NULL and non-NULL rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been counting NULL and non-NULL columns with a subselect and some aggregate functions

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE citizens(name text, country text,profession text,postalcode text);

INSERT INTO citizens VALUES
 ('Fred', 'USA', 'Professor', NULL),
 ('Amy', 'USA', 'Professor', NULL),
 ('Ted', 'USA', 'Professor', 90210),
 ('Barb', 'USA', 'Lawyer', 10248),
 ('Wally', 'USA', 'Lawyer', NULL),
 ('Fred', 'Canada', 'Professor', 'S0H'),
 ('Charles', 'Canada', 'Professor', 'S4L'),
 ('Nancy', 'Canada', 'Lawyer', NULL),
 ('Linda', 'Canada', 'Professor', NULL),
 ('Steph', 'France', 'Lawyer', 75008 ),
 ('Arnold', 'France', 'Lawyer', 75008 ),
 ('Penny', 'France', 'Lawyer', 75008 ),
 ('Harry', 'France', 'Lawyer', NULL);

SELECT country,
    profession,
    MAX(have_postalcode::int*num) AS num_have,
    MAX((1-have_postalcode::int)*num) AS num_not_have
FROM
    (
    SELECT country, profession,
        COUNT(*) AS num,
        (postalcode IS NOT NULL) AS have_postalcode
    FROM citizens
    GROUP BY country, profession, have_postalcode
    ) AS d
GROUP BY country, profession
```

with the result

```
USA     Professor   1   2
Canada  Lawyer      0   1
USA     Lawyer      1   1
France  Lawyer      3   1
Canada  Professor   2   1
```

but it seems like there ought to be a slicker way (for example it pains me that `MAX` is used just to grab the one nontrivial value).   Does anybody have a cool idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT country, profession,
        COUNT(postalcode) AS num_have
      , (COUNT(*) - COUNT(postalcode)) AS num_not_have
FROM citizens
GROUP BY country, profession;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/17a9d/15

Comment: I didn't know about sqlfiddle.com.  Great find!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  country
,       profession
,       sum(case when postalcode is not null then 1 end) as num_have
,       sum(case when postalcode is null then 1 end) as num_not_have
FROM    citizens
GROUP BY 
        country
,       profession
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Country, Profession, 
    count(Country) as num_have, count(*) - count(PostalCode) as num_not_have
FROM citizens
GROUP BY Country, Profession
```

Comment: `count(Country)` counts all rows with a non-null country.  You're probably looking for `count(postalcode)` and `count(*) - count(postalcode)`

Comment: Even the author agrees this answer is wrong.  But it still gets three upvotes and is the accepted answer.  Weird.

Comment: The second part of `count(Country) - count(State)` is pretty wrong though ;)

Comment: Knowing COUNT() ignores NULLs is the essential item from my point of view (it was news to me) and Z.D. was first to post using that.  But I'm switching the accepted answer due to closh having the first correct answer.

Comment: @BrianB: If you value the "essential element" then *fix* the answer or leave a comment for the author to fix it (like Andomar did) before accepting. And the author should fix it - and give credit to whoever pointed it out. You shouldn't accept a wrong answer. Nor vote for it, really. Innocent bystanders will be fooled.

Comment: @Erwin.  You're absolutely right.  To be honest, I hadn't noticed Mr. Danev had a mistake when I accepted, since the problem I posted was toy version of my real one.  Copying his idea for COUNT had worked to solve my problem, meaning the first clue I had about the error Andomar's comments, posted after I had already accepted.  Given that had happened, should I have switched acceptance as I did, or waited for a fix?  I appreciate your guidance in the etiquette of the site.

Comment: @BrianB: The details always come down to personal choice. In the end the best answer should be accepted. If there are several equally good, pick the first among them. Upvote others that added helpful information. If you find a mistake, leave a comment or, if it's trivial and you have the necessary privileges, fix it yourself right away. To get a feel for the etiquette look at some of the discussions on meta, like [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80788/which-answer-should-i-accept) or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28276/169168).